# How to obtain a special solution for a nonlinear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Recently, I try to solve some PDE through numerical way. Then, I found that it was hard to judge whether the method performed good or bad because in many cases, it seems to be hard to obtain a special solution. For example, the Burgers equation:
\begin{equation}
u_t + uu_x = \delta u_{xx},\ \ \delta\ \mbox{is constant.}
\end{equation}

How can I obtain a special solution for this equation?

And, I wonder that if there is a good way to find a special solution for any PDE easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several types of especial solutions that you can try foe Burger's equation (and many others):

- **Stationary solutions**: $u(x)$
- T**raveling wave solutions**: $u(x,t)=\phi(x-c\,t)$, where $\phi$ is a one variable function and $c$ is the (unknown) speed of the wave.
- **Self similar solutions**. If $u(x,t)$ is a solution of Burger's equation, so is $u_\lambda(x,t)=\lambda\,u(\lambda\,x,\lambda^2\,t)$. Self similar solutions are solutions such that $u_\lambda=u$. They are of the form $u(x,t)=t^{-1/2}\psi(x\,t^{-1/2})$.

Looking for these special  solutions leads to an ordinary differential equation that can be solved explicitely.

Comment: Through self similar solutions, I got a nonlinear ODE. But I am not sure it can be solved analytically.

Comment: Let $z=x\,t^{-1/2}$. The equation is $$-\frac12\,(\psi+z\,\psi')+\psi\,\psi'=\delta\,\psi''.$$ This can be integrated once to get $$-\frac12\,z\psi+\frac12\,\psi^2=\delta\,\psi'+C.$$ For $C=0$ this is a Bernoulli equation.

Answer (score 0):

A special solution always depends on the specified boundary conditions. There is no general method, since it depends on the kind of boundary conditions.

If the boundary conditions are not given, it is impossible to answer to your question. Moreover, if the boundary conditions are given, a method to solve the PDE analytically is available only in a few cases.

Comment: If I know some features about the exact solution (e.g. diffusion), would it be helpful?

Comment: Knowing something is always helpful. But helpful to what problem exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm for finding asymptotic solutions for nonlinear partial differential equations, a little trick I picked up in Oak Ridge in the 90's.  It doesn't work every time because it utilizes one family of infinite stretching groups that is invariant to most, but not all PDEs.  It uses group theory, specifically Lie Theory, and has its roots in the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, which is a counting theorem.

It is easiest to explain if you write out the PDE as fractions and partial derivatives as follows:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{u}{1}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\delta}{1}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

Count the variables in each monomial, setting those in each numerator as positive and those in each denominator as negative, and then set them equal to each other, as shown.

$$u-t=2u-x=\delta+u-2x$$

$u-t=2u_1-x \rightarrow u_1=x-t$  The first solution is $u_1(x,t)=\frac{Cx}{t}$
If you take derivatives of this and plug them back into the equation you find that the  value of C = 1.  Therefore, the first solution is $u_1=\frac{x}{t}$

$2u_2-x=\delta+u-2x \rightarrow u_2=\delta-x$ Therefore, $u_2(x)=\frac{D\delta}{x}$  Plugging in derivatives provides the value of D=-2.  The second solution is $u_2=\frac{-2\delta}{x}$.

Occasionally, as is the case with Burger's equation, you may add these solutions together and get a more complete asymptotic solution to the equation:

$$u(x,t)=\frac{x}{t}-\frac{2\delta}{x}$$

If you want to have some fun, go to Wikipedia and look up the "list of nonlinear partial differential equations."  Some of those equations may be solved this way.